# How to evaluate Integrate[Exp[Csch[(x - τ)]^2], {x, 0, x}]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I have been trying to integrate the following and Mathematica couldn't integrate it. Can someone help me on this?

```
Assuming[{Element[{x, τ}, Reals], x > 0, τ > 0, (x - τ) != 0},
  Integrate[Exp[Csch[(x - τ)]^2], {x, 0, x}]]
```

Comment: What does it mean that you want to integrate the variable x from 0 to x?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  If $\tau >0$ and the integral goes from $x=0$, then there will always be a value where $x=\tau$.

Comment: I assume you mean, `Assuming[{Element[{x, τ}, Reals], x > 0, τ > 0, (x - τ) != 0},
  Integrate[Exp[Csch[(x - τ)]^2], {τ, 0, x}]]`.  The integral is infinite.

Comment: `ParametricNDSolve[]` is usable for this.

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon. I think my answer implements something similar to what `ParametricNDSolve`  would do.

Answer (score 3):

The integral doesn't seem to have any closed form solution. You can get an approximation to it by building an interpolating function and integrating it. Like so:

```
Clear[f, pts, ff, int]
f[τ_][u_] := Exp[Csch[(u - τ)]^2]; 
ff[τ_, x_, dx_] := Interpolation[Table[{u, f[τ][u]}, {u, 0, x, dx}]]; 
int[x_, dx_][τ_] := Function[u, Integrate[ff[τ, x, dx][uu], {uu, 0, u}]]
```

Then, given `τ = 2, x = 1.25, dx = .001`, we can use `int[x, dx][τ]` as function that behaves like the function that is the integral of `f`. For example:

```
With[{τ = 2, x = 1.25, dx = .001},
  Plot[{f[τ][u], int[x, dx][τ][u]}, {u, 0, x}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you @m_goldberg. Can you also look at (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210534/double-integration-of-an-exponential-function-which-includes-a-csch-function-and) and give me an input? Appreciate it.

Comment: @Sankalpa. That is a much more difficult integral to deal with. The techniques I used here might help, but using them would require a lot of non-trivial effort. I don't  have the spare time to make such an effort.

Comment: I totally understand. Thank you for sharing this solution with me. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @JM, you can use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue) to obtain a numerical approximation to your integral:

```
pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {
    int'[u] == Exp[Csch[u-τ]^2],
    int[0] == 0
    },
    int,
    {u, 0, τ-.1}, (* avoid singularity at τ *)
    τ
];
```

Visualization (using @m_goldbergs settings):

```
Plot[{Exp[Csch[x-2]^2], pf[2][x]}, {x, 0, 1.25}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Carl Woll